# Form is reseting which let ng-change function to stop working until new row is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My ng-change="autoFillIngDet(iteration.iteration_detail[$index].INCI_name, $index)" worked well until i used $scope.addNewIteration = [{}]; in my form reset function that helps in reseting multiple rows to its initial state.

//This is my html code.

```
<form name="iterationForm" ng-submit="addNewRow()" id="resetAdd">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{'AddIteration' | translate}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">{{'Date' | translate}}<span class="compulsary"> * </span></label>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control " placeholder="" name="date" ng-model="iteration.date"  autocomplete="off" required data-ng-init="init()">
            <div ng-messages="iterationForm.date.$error" ng-if="iterationForm.date.$dirty" role="alert" id="error">
              <span ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">{{'PackageName' | translate}}<span class="compulsary"> * </span></label>
             <select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="status" ng-model="iteration.packageName" required>
              <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
              <option ng-repeat="p in packageList" value="p.packaging_id">{{p.inci_name}}</option>
            </select>
            <div ng-messages="iterationForm.PackageName.$error" ng-if="iterationForm.PackageName.$dirty" role="alert" id="error">
              <span ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">{{'Comments' | translate}}<span class="compulsary"> * </span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="comment" ng-model="iteration.comment" required>
            <div ng-messages="iterationForm.comment.$error" ng-if="iterationForm.comment.$dirty" role="alert" id="error">
              <span ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">{{'Status' | translate}} <span class="compulsary"> * </span></label>
            <select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="status" ng-model="iteration.status" required>
              <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
              <option value="1">Fail</option>
              <option value="2">Final</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">{{'TentativeCostUnit' | translate}}<span class="compulsary"> * </span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="tentativeCost" ng-model="iteration.tentativeCost" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" required>
            <div ng-messages="iterationForm.tentativeCost.$error" ng-if="iterationForm.tentativeCost.$dirty" role="alert" id="error">
              <span ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</span>
              <span ng-message="pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div>
              <label class="control-label">{{'Procedure' | translate}}</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="" file-input="files" file-model="iteration.procedure" accept=".pdf" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" required>
              <span style="color: blue">{{errMessage}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center">{{'INCIName' | translate}}</th>
                <th class="text-center">{{'BatchNo' | translate}}</th>
                <th class="text-center">{{'Percentage' | translate}}</th>
                <th class="text-center">{{'Quantity' | translate}}</th>
                <th class="text-center">{{'PriceCostUnit' | translate}}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="iteration_row in addNewIteration">
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="hidden" ng-model="iteration.iteration_detail[$index].ingredient_id">
                        <select class="form-control" name="INCI_name" ng-model="iteration.iteration_detail[$index].INCI_name" ng-change="autoFillIngDet(iteration.iteration_detail[$index].INCI_name, $index)" required>
                          <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                          <option value="{{ing.inci_name}}"  ng-repeat="ing in dropdownIngIteration">{{ing.inci_name}}</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="batch_no" ng-model="iteration.iteration_detail[$index].batch_no" value="{{ing.batch_number}}" required>
                        <div ng-messages="iterationForm.batch_no.$error" ng-if="iterationForm.batch_no.$dirty" role="alert" id="error">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="percentage" ng-model="iteration.iteration_detail[$index].percentage" ng-pattern="/(^100(\.0{1,2})?$)|(^([1-9]([0-9])?|0)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)/" required ng-change = "updateIterationData(iteration.iteration_detail[$index])" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="quantity" ng-model="iteration.iteration_detail[$index].quantity" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" ng-change="calculatePriceOnQty(iteration.iteration_detail[$index].quantity, $index)" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="price" ng-model="iteration.iteration_detail[$index].price"  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg" title="Add More" value="+">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="addIterations(iteration)" ng-disabled="iterationForm.$invalid || tick !== 'true'">{{'Add' | translate}}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{{'Cancel' | translate}}</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

//this function is to generate multiple rows with 5 input fields.

```
$scope.addNewIteration = [{}];
$scope.addNewRow = function(addNewIteration){
    $scope.addNewIteration.push({
        'INCI_name' : "",
        'batch_no' : "",
        'percentage' : "",
        'quantity' : "",
        'price' : "",
        'formula_id': 0
    });
$scope.AN = {};
};
```

//this is to reset the entire form.

```
$scope.refreshAdd=function(){
   $scope.addNewIteration = [{}];   /*this line i expected to reset multiple rows which is also aborting the ng-change="autoFillIngDet()" to work */
   document.getElementById("resetAdd").reset();
   $scope.iterationForm.$setPristine();
   $scope.iteration = null;
 }
```

//I have to keep ng-change function work even its field gets reset. Please help me if anybody can. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try like this:

```
$scope.addNewIteration = [];
```